# Flutter ios error: use of undeclared identifier on build and run

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, deployment

I am trying to build my flutter application on ios, it already runs on android my xcode. my xcode version is 13.3 and after running flutter doctor my flutter setup seems fine
when I try running my flutter code on ios using a simulator I keep getting this error

```
/Users/anthony/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/just_audio-0.9.36/macos/Classes/UriAudioSource.m:53:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey'; did you mean 'AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey'?
                        assetOptions[AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey] = userAgent;
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey
In module 'AVFoundation' imported from /Users/anthony/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/just_audio-0.9.36/macos/Classes/IndexedPlayerItem.h:1:
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15), ios(8.0), tvos(9.0), watchos(1.0));
                           ^
1 error generated.
** BUILD FAILED **

Exception: Build process failed
```

If i try running `flutter build ios` it brings up a simillar error

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           72.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey'; did you mean 'AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey'?
/Users/anthony/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/just_audio-0.9.36/ios/Classes/UriAudioSource.m:52:37


Error (Xcode): Interrupted


Encountered error while building for device.
```

I have deleted my ios folder and restarted the app but it does not go away. The libraries I am using on flutter are:

```yaml
dependencies:
  animated_list_plus: ^0.5.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  confetti: ^0.7.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  easy_pie_chart: ^1.0.0
  either_dart: ^1.0.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  expandable_widgets: ^1.0.3+1
  file_picker: ^5.2.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.7.2
  firebase_core: ^2.24.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.3.6
  fl_chart: ^0.63.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.1.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  flutter_timezone: ^1.0.8
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.14.6
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
  google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
  grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.1
  infinite_listview: ^1.1.0
  intl: ^0.18.0
  lottie: ^2.6.0
  page_transition: ^2.1.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  permission_handler: ^10.4.5
  responsive_sizer: ^3.2.0
  scroll_date_picker: ^3.7.3
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.1.0
  step_progress_indicator: ^1.0.2
  tab_container: ^2.0.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.9
  timer_count_down: ^2.2.2
  timezone: ^0.9.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.8
  uuid: ^4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey` requires at least iOS 16, see the official document at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlassethttpuseragentkey).

You are using Xcode 13.3 which only supports up to iOS 15.4, see the official document at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/).

You have several options to proceed, the easiest is to upgrade to at least Xcode 14 to build with iOS 16.

In case you are using an older version of macOS and cannot upgrade Xcode, you will need to downgrade `just_audio` package to `v0.9.35` because `AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey` usage was first introduce in that version, see [github.com](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/commit/977e81d). Adding this to `pubspec.yaml` should be enough:

```yaml
dependencies:
  just_audio: 0.9.35
```